# Url query string in fetch api in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api

How to pass query string with `fetch` api javascript (https://github.com/github/fetch)?

```
var url = "http://www.abcd.com";
var query = {
    a: "test",
    b: 2
};
```

Above should be converted to `http://www.abcd.com?a=test&b=2` when I pass some argument to `fetch`

Answer (score 7):

```
var params = Object.keys(query)
                   .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(query[key]))
                   .join("&")
                   .replace(/%20/g, "+");

fetch(url + "?" + params);
```

Or with the `options` object - [but this will **NOT** work with `GET` and `HEAD` method](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request):

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: convertObjectToFormData(query)
}).then(...);

function convertObjectToFormData(obj) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    for (var key in obj) {
        formData.append(key, obj[key]);
    }
    return formData;
}
```

Comment: There is no query support in `fetch`?

Comment: You can pass them as `body` in the `options` object, but you will have to convert them to `URLSearchParams` (not supported yet) or FormData. See my edit for an example.

Comment: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body` @Andreas, I'm getting above error when I tried your example

Comment: Sorry. Looks like I thought `window.fetch` works like jQuery (or any other library) and it will put the params from `body` as a querystring if the method is `GET`. But the [Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request) (step 31) doesn't allow a `body` on `GET` and `HEAD` requests... So you will have to stick with option one or change the method to `POST`